# error onchange is not function render conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I don't understand why functions are not recognized as such when they are inside a condition. The page retrieves the user's data, and when the user clicks on the edit button the inputs appear instead. Everything works, except I get in console that onChange is not a function. Is it possible to correct or must the code be modified? thank you for help

```
const DataUser = ()=>{
    const [lastname, setLastname] = useState("")
    const [updateInfoUser, setUpdateInfoUser] = useState(false)
   return(
    <>
      <div>
          <h3 >name:</h3>
           {   
             updateInfoUser=== true ? <input type="text" name="nom" onChange={(e) => (setLastname(e.target.value))} />
            : <div>
                 <p>{user.lastname}</p>
              </div>
           }
       </div>
    </>
)

}
```

Comment: What edit button?

Comment: `except I get in console that onChange is not a function` I don't see how that error could be caused by the code you've shown. Is this all the code?

Comment: I don't get the error you claim you are getting. See example here: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-gauss-ekp3cr) Could you provide an example in codesandbox or something similar that produces your error message?

Comment: Yes I made a codesendbox a little lower to show how it is on my code @Tour Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

**Try using round brackets**

Like this:

````
    const [lastname, setLastname] = useState("")
    const [updateInfoUser, setUpdateInfoUser] = useState(false)
   return(
    <>
      <div>
          <h3>name:</h3>
           {   
             updateInfoUser=== true ? (
             <input type="text" name="nom" onChange={(e) => (setLastname(e.target.value))} />
           ) : (
              <div>
                 <p>{user.lastname}</p>
              </div>
             )
           }
       </div>
    </>
)

} ```
````

Comment: yes i tried i still got the same error @Mohamed Ali

Answer (score 0):

**Try to call function inside onChange and define it at the top**

Like this:

```
    const [updateInfoUser, setUpdateInfoUser] = useState(false)

    const onChange = e => {
       setLastname(e.target.value)
    }

   return(
    <>
      <div>
          <h3>name:</h3>
           {   
             updateInfoUser=== true ? (
             <input type="text" name="nom" onChange={onChange} />
           ) : (
              <div>
                 <p>{user.lastname}</p>
              </div>
             )
           }
       </div>
    </>
)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this code
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-leftpad-e6yvk2?file=/src/Input.js

change setLastname from props to setlastname.

L in setLastname is lower case.

fix this typo.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my codeSendBox @Saleh shokouhi, on my original code I checked for typing errors and I can't find any. I think I'll put them all back in the same component because it works that way. The only problem is that the component has a lot of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your solutions, I just saw where the error came from, I passed the props from the child to the parents, mistake of intention.